# Unable to autosign certificates for Puppet

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

I have a new Puppet server set up and am unable to currently get autosigning of certificates to work.

I've followed the setup instructions on https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/config_file_autosign but adding hostnames to the file leads to an error when starting the server:

```
Execution error (ConfigException$Parse) at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigDocumentParser>$ParseContext/parseError (ConfigDocumentParser.java:201).
/etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/conf.d/autosign.conf: 1: expecting a close parentheses ')' here, not: '*' (Reserved character '*' is not allowed outside quotes)
```

I've also tried putting `autosign = true` in `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf` but this is not autosigning the certificates either.

Comment: The error seems clear to me. You have a wildcard character that needs to be in quotes. Maybe post some of the config so we can help more?